# How to Make DB9 F/F serial RS232 mini gender changer?

Tags: serial, rs232, diy, db9

I want to connect My "USB to RS232(Male end)" to my NanoVolt Meter having RS232 male port. To make both communicate i need to make DB9 F/F serial RS232 mini gender changer. Any Circuit or suggestion will be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: The thing you first need to determine is if you need just the gender changer or if you need a null modem cable (rx and tx lines crossed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Finbarr and JRE.

The Connection i was looking for was found in the manual of instrument:

[image]

Outcome:[image]

Comment: Glad to hear you found it.  The manual is always a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is a pure gender changer, I wouldn't bother making one because they're easy enough to buy:

[image]

Just search for DB9F Gender Changer or something similar.

You could make one yourself by getting two DB9F connectors and soldering nine short wires between them and using long threaded studs to link them together but it's a lot of work for nothing and it would probably cost you more in parts. But if you need to do anything more complex than simply changing gender, such as making a crossover adapter, you'll have to go down this path.

Check the data sheets for the USB converter and the meter to find out what connections you need to make.